# Electronic configuration of Co³⁺

Tags: electronic-configuration

Cobalt (atomic number 27) has electronic configuration $[\ce{Ar}]\mathrm{(4s)^2 (3d)^7}.$

I have seen two different configurations and explanations for $\ce{Co^3+}$ from a variety of different sources:

1. either it loses two $\mathrm{4s}$ electrons and becomes $[\ce{Ar}]\mathrm{(3d)^6}$ in accordance with aufbau principle;
2. or it loses one $\mathrm{4s}$ electron and two $\mathrm{3d}$ electrons to become $[\ce{Ar}]\mathrm{4s (3d)^5}$ which is supposedly more stable due to its half filled orbitals and lack of electron pairs.

I think the one with more stability or lesser energy will be the one which is correct, but how can I find this out without experimental data? And what is the right answer?